# Restarting connection with python socketserver

Tags: python, python-3.x, socketserver

I am creating a server with Python 3 socketserver and I have an issue while trying to restart the connection. I want to be able to close it, read configuration from a file and start again, however, I am running into the `Address already in use` OSError. I thought that using `server_close()` method it would clear itself (as specified in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.BaseServer.server_close)) so that I will be able to start again with it, but I'm not.

Here is my code:

```
class NetworkCommunicationService(Services):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__connection__ = None
        self.__setup__()

    def __setup__(self):
        host, port = get_setup()
        self.__connection__ = ConnectionHandler.setup_connection_handler(host, port)

    def service_entry_point(self):
        try:
            self.__connect__()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            Output.config_error()
        finally:
            self.__connection__.shutdown()

    def __connect__(self):
            self.__connection__.serve_forever()

    def terminate(self):
        self.__connection__.shutdown()
        self.__connection__.server_close()

    def reset(self):
        self.terminate()
        self.__setup__()
        self.service_entry_point()
```

The `handle()` method called in `serve_forever()` is taken from some website I can't remember right now. I only added the `close()` at the end hoping it would help.

```
def handle(self):
    # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
    self.data = self.request.recv(1024)
    print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
    print(self.data)
    # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
    self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())
    self.request.close()
```

What shall I do to be able to reset the connection?